# Yahoo Boss getJson

Tags: json, getjson, yahoo-boss-api

Anyone know how to do a JSON call to the Yahoo Boss API? Ideally the URL for the documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YBoss](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/yboss/) is a JSON wrapper for the Yahoo Boss API. I believe Yahoo Boss talks XML natively.

UPDATE: Yahoo BOSS JSON Search API will discontinue on March 31, 2016.
https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/

Answer (score 0):

I think Yahoo BOSS returns the results in JSON by default, unless you explicitly pass a format=xml argument to the request.
So, for example, in Python you could do something like

```
import simplejson
import urllib2
result = simplejson.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/foo?appid=xyz'))
```